# Convergence rate of $a_{n+1}=\ln(a_n+1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\ln(a_n+1)$. The goal is to find 
$$
(\star)\quad \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n(na_n-2)}{\ln n}
$$

It is easy to see that $a_n\to 0$. 
In addition, we can prove that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}na_n=2.
$$
Indeed, one can obtain by  Stolz's theorem that 
\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_n}} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)-n}{\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}} \\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\ln(1+a_n)}-\frac{1}{a_n}} \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n\ln(1+a_n)}{a_n-\ln(1+a_n)}  \\ &=2 , \end{align}
How to estimate the further limit $(\star)$?

Comment: How did you guess that this was the correct asymptotic expansion?

Answer (score 4):

Introduce inverse sequence $b_n=1/a_n$:
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\ln{(1+1/b_n)}}$$
It was already proved that:
$$
b_n=\frac{n}{2}+o(n)
$$
Then:
$$S=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n(na_n-2)}{\ln n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n-2b_n)}{\ln n}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2(n-2b_n)}{\ln n}$$
Using Stolz's theorem:
$$S=2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1-2b_{n+1})-(n-2b_n)}{\ln{(n+1)}-\ln{n}}$$
$$=2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2b_n+1-2/\ln^{}{(1+1/b_n)}}{1/n}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1/n}{\ln{(n+1)}-\ln{n}}$$
$$=2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1/(6b_n)}{1/n}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Numerics siggest that $na_n>2$ for $n\ge 872$.

Comment: I think the 6 should actually be a 2

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ denote the limit in the OP. Then
$$
a_n=\frac{2}{n}+\frac{L\log n}{n^2}+\mathcal O(n^{-3}\log n)
$$
and
$$
\log(a_{n-1}+1)=\frac{2}{n}+\frac{L\log n}{n^2}+\frac{\frac23-L}{n^3}+\mathcal O(n^{-3}\log n)
$$

Insisting that both expansions are identical requires $L=\frac23$. A similar technique can be used to obtain higher order corrections.