# Consider $a_n = \ln(1 + a_{n-1})$ with $a_0 = 1/2$. Show the limit is $0$ and find the radius of convergence (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion, limsup-and-liminf

Consider $a_n = \ln(1 + a_{n-1})$ with $a_0 = \frac{1}{2}$. Show the limit is $0$ and find the radius of convergence

I have seen these:

[Find limit of $a_n = \ln (1 + a_{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007044/find-limit-of-a-n-ln-1-a-n-1)

[Convergence rate of $a_{n+1}=\ln(a_n+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984673/convergence-rate-of-a-n1-lna-n1)

But on both the initial condition is different, and the second one seems to be asking for something different.

First, let's find the limit. I argued that $a_n$ is monotone decreasing.

In general, $e^x \geq 1 + x$ unless $x = 0$. But, $a_0 = 1/2$, so $a_n \neq 0 \ \forall x$. Therefore, I can say:

$e^{a_n} \geq 1 + a_n$

$a_n \geq \ln(1 + a_n) = a_{n+1}$

Since $a_n \geq 0$ and $a_n$ is decreasing, we can conclude that its limit is $0$.

Does this look ok? I have not worked very much with recursive sequences, so I want to make sure I'm doing ok.

Now, let's work on the radius of convergence.

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is what we want to compute. I am going to drop the limit as I won't actually end up needing it for what I attempted (which is a bit of a red flag for me, but it's all I could think to try).

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\ln(1+a_n)}{\ln(1+a_{n-1})} = \ln(a_n - a_{n-1}) = \ln(\ln(a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})) = \dots = \ln(\ln(\dots(\ln(a_1 - a_0)))\dots) = \ln(\ln(\dots(\ln(a_1 - \frac{1}{2})))\dots)$

Now, I already showed that $a_n$ was decreasing. So, $a_1 - \frac{1}{2} <0$ and this means the limit does not exist. Now, I know the $\limsup_{n \to -\infty} \ln(n) = \infty$. Making a change of variable, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \ln(-n) = \infty$ still. Therefore, I believe the limsup is $\infty$ which means $R = 0$.

Does everything look ok here? Did I mess up on any parts?

Comment: $a_n=1+1/n$ is non-negative and decreasing, but its limit is not zero. You can conclude that the limit exists, though. Taking limits on $a_{n+1}=\ln(1+a_n)$ and calling the limit $L$ you would get that $L=\ln(1+L)$, from where you can conclude that $L=0$. For the second part, leave $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim\frac{\ln(1+a_n)}{a_n}$ and use that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$.

Comment: in De Bruijn,  chapter 8  is Iterated Functions. Section 8.4  is called Slow Convergence, which applies here because the derivative of $\log(1+x)$ at $0$  is $1$  He does the example $\sin x $ in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general, $e^x \geq 1+x$ unless $x = 0$

I guess you meant to say that $e^x > 1+x$? Now, you actually should explicitly show that $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. The proof is just a simple induction argument.

Indeed, $a_0 > 0$. Next, assume that $a_n > 0$ for some arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Then:
$$a_{n+1} = \log(a_{n+1}+1) > 0$$
since $\log$ is a strictly increasing function. Your conclusion that your sequence is decreasing is correct and since it is bounded below, it is convergent with limit $L$. It would, then, follow that:
$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \log(1+a_n) = \log(1+L)$$
due to the continuity of $L$. This is only possible when $L = 0$. That would be a much more complete argument.

As for your computation of the radius of convergence, you've overcomplicated it significantly. It does not follow that:
$$\frac{\log(1+a_n)}{\log(1+a_{n-1})} = \log(a_n-a_{n-1})$$

Since every $a_n > 0$, we have that:
$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+a_n)}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+a_n)-\log(1)}{a_n}$$

By the sequential limit criterion, the right-hand side is just the derivative of $x \mapsto \log(x)$ at $x = 1$. So, it follows that $R = 1$.